# Solveing integral with numerical methods

Tags: numerical-methods

I want to solve this integral with numerical method (for example Trapezoidal). $u$ in It's dominant is variable. My question is Can I use the numerical methods for solve these integrals? [image]

Answer (score 0):

Given a function $g(x;u,t)$ with parameters $u$ and $t$ you could try the [trapezoidal rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule):

$$\int_a^b g(x;u,t)dx = \frac{h}{2}\left(y_0+2(y_1+y_2+\cdots+y_{n-1})+y_n\right),$$
where $h=(b-a)/n$. In your case $g(v;u,t)=(v-u)f(v;t)$ for some function $f(v;t)$.

You would need to fix parameters $u$ and $t$ to get an actual numerical value.

Whether this method gives you a satisfactory result depends on the function $g$, e.g. [pathological functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathological_%28mathematics%29) may prove problematic!

For example, suppose we want to evaluate $$\int_0^1x^2dx$$ using the trapezoidal rule. Here the function $g$ is $g(x)=x^2$. Let's choose $n=5$ *partitions* of the *domain* $[0,1]$. Then $h=(1-0)/5 = 0.2$. The values $y_k$ are just the values of the function $g(x)$ evaluated at $x=a$, $x=a+h$, $x=a+2h$, $\ldots$, $x=b$.
 So the integral becomes $$\int_0^1 x^2dx = \frac{0.2}{2}(g(0)+2(g(0.2)+g(0.4)+g(0.6)+g(0.8))+g(1)) = 0.34.$$ The exact value of the integral is $1/3$, which is approximately $0.33$. The more partitions you use the better the approximation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you please explain How can we create g function

Comment: The function $g$ can be any function you want ! - See example above.